# Expected value of a "logistic uniform" multivariate

Tags: sampling, expected-value, monte-carlo, approximation, importance-sampling

Let $\mathbf{a}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{a}_n \in \mathbb R^d$ and $b_1,\ldots,b_n \in \mathbb R$ be fixed.  For $\mathbf{x} \sim \mathcal U([0,1]^d)$ and $j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$, consider the real variable defined by the softmax / "logistic" transformation

$$y_j(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{\exp(\mathbf{a}_j^T \mathbf{x} + b_j)}{\sum_{k=1}^n\exp(\mathbf{a_k}^T\mathbf{x} + b_k)}.
$$

I'm interesting in an **efficient** way to compute the expected value of $y_j$.

**Poorman's solution:**

- Draw $\mathbf{x}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_N \sim \mathcal U([0,1]^d)$
- Compute the empirical mean $\hat{\mu}_N(y_j) := \frac{1}{N}\sum_i^N y_j(\mathbf{x}_i)$.

For sure, $\hat{\mu}_N(y_j) \overset{N \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb E_{\mathbf{x} \sim \mathcal U([0,1]^d)} [y_j(\mathbf{x})]$ by law of large numbers.

**Question:**

- How to make the above "poorman's solution" faster (i.e high accuracy with small $N$) ?
- How can "importance sampling" be used to accomplish this ?

**Details** will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you assuming $x_i$ are uniform? Wouldn't it make more sense to assume they are sampled from your data distribution?

Comment: It's not just an artificial assumption, it's part of the problem data...

Comment: not importance sampling, but for small $d$, quasi-Monte Carlo would give you a better convergence rate w.r.t $N$

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts on this problem which might be of interest: your predictor can be interpreted as the Bayes classifier for a Gaussian mixture model. For example, if you take $r \in \mathbf{R}^d, Q \succ  0$, then

\begin{align}
y_j(x) &= \frac{\omega_j \mathcal{N} \left( x | \mu_j, Q^{-1} \right)}{\sum_{k=1}^n \omega_k \mathcal{N} \left( x  | \mu_k, Q^{-1} \right)} \\
\text{where} \quad\omega_k &= \exp \left( b_k + \frac{1}{2} |a_k + r|_{Q^{-1}}^2 \right) \\
\mu_k &= Q^{-1} \left( a_k + r \right).
\end{align}

Your quantity of interest can be expressed as "given a uniform sample from the hypercube, what is the probability that it came from the $j^{\text{th}}$ component of this GMM?". This naturally suggests a simple importance sampling scheme which puts most of its mass near the $j^{\text{th}}$ mode, e.g.

\begin{align}
q_j (x) = \alpha_0 \cdot \mathbb{I} \left[ x \in [0,1]^d \right] + \alpha_1 \cdot \mathcal{N} \left( x  | \mu_j, \gamma \cdot Q^{-1} \right)
\end{align}

where $(\alpha_0, \alpha_1, \gamma)$ are tunable parameters. One could also consider importance distributions based on the full $n$-component mixture, e.g.

\begin{align}
q^n (x) = \alpha_0 \cdot \mathbb{I} \left[ x \in [0,1]^d \right] + \sum_{k = 1}^n \alpha_k \mathcal{N} \left( x  | \mu_k, \gamma \cdot Q^{-1} \right),
\end{align}

which induces additional tuning parameters, which has its costs and benefits. Of course, there is the complication of setting $(r, Q)$ as well. My guess is that if one can set $(r, Q)$ such that the support of the implied GMM overlaps well with the hypercube as a whole (by some measure), this will give well-behaved weights for a derived importance sampling scheme.

My suspicion here is that if one can find a good way of setting $(r, Q)$, then life is not too hard: one can use the above construction to parametrise a family of importance densities, and then apply standard adaptive importance sampling techniques, possibly also using some extra variance reduction tricks like QMC / stratification and control variates to sweeten the deal.

I hope this is at least somewhat useful. I am a little frustrated that I lack intuition for how to set $(r, Q)$ automatically, as once that is done, the problem is relatively friendly. One idea would be to try to tune $(r, Q)$ such that

\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 1}^K w_k \textbf{Var}_{\mathcal{N} \left( x  | \mu_k, Q^{-1} \right)} \left( y_j (x) \cdot \mathbb{I} \left[ x \in [0,1]^d \right] \right)
\end{align}

is minimal, though it should be emphasised that this is just a heuristic.